# Connection refused on Devise forgotten password, in RoR app deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, mandrill

I'm trying to use devise gem in my RoR app. It's working fine, except in production mode I cannot receive emails for forgotten passwords. The page shows this error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Devise::PasswordsController#create
Connection refused - connect(2)

Rails.root: /app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"S8rQE7SyT4+7gLvwIiFG+violKPAhzzKMZKUiH0xUSU=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"myemail@whatever.com"},
 "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
```

I should mention that:

- I have run the db migration on heroku, with no errors.
- It is working fine in development (emails are sent)
- I'm using mandrill
- heroku logs shows some kind of heroku router error:

> ```
> heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/password" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id
> =7e327911-49cb-448a-aa33-13f4bda8c3f dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=351ms status=500 bytes=1754
> ```

---

My mailer configurations from **production.rb** are the same as those from **development.rb**:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# change to true to allow email to be sent during development
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: ENV["MAIL_ADDRESS"],
  port: 587,
  user_name: ENV["MAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["MAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Additionally, in **production.rb** I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myappname.herokuapp.com'}
```

while in **development.rb** I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

The **database.yml** file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  user: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  port: 5432

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME_DEV'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME_TEST'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME_PROD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

I was using Figaro gem to store my environmental data, but these keys even though they were available in development, had to be made visible for heroku. Only after this additional step they can be used in production:

```
$ figaro heroku:set
```

Alternatively you can set these variable by using:

```
$ heroku config:add <key>=<value>
```